# Efficient way to take difference of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, list-comprehension

I'm moving a particle along a straight trajectory and dividing the trajectory by N where N is a large number. Then I do some calculations based on its position and store these in 7 different lists. The whole process takes about 0.03 seconds which is great.

However, then using these lists, I create difference lists where the elements of d_list are simply list[n+1]-list[n] for all n. To do that I use the following code

```
d_lists = [[np.abs(b-a) for a,b in zip(l, l[1:])] for l in lists]
```

And when I do this, now it takes 7.7 seconds which is tremendously high compared to 0.03 seconds. I tried following to reduce to time, but it took about 13 seconds.

```
d_lists = [[abs_diff for abs_diff in map(np.abs, zip(l, l[1:]))]
```

I'm curious if there is a better way to approach this problem. I'm having a hard time intuitively understanding why this simple task takes a lot of time.

One thing I noticed is np.abs causing this. If I just do (b-a) instead np.abs(b-a) then 7.7 seconds reduces to 1.2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

#### Have you tried `np.diff`?

This gives you sequential differences in an array, without your current process of converting each tuple (a,b) from a standard python result b-a, and then running a numpy function.

```
d_lists = [np.abs(np.diff(l)) for l in lists]
```

#### Is it possible to have the lists themselves as numpy arrays?

That would probably make it even faster. Each conversion from a native Python variable to and from NumPy probably incurs a small overhead, which in your current case is being massively repeated.

#### For maximum efficiency you could store all the lists in a *single* numpy array

I think this is possible because you seem to be saying that the 7 lists are effectively parallel, i.e. they are of equal length.

If so then you can use `np.diff` and specify which "axis" you want it to diff along.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html

> ```
> numpy.diff(a, n=1, axis=-1, prepend=<no value>, append=<no value>)
>
> Calculate the n-th discrete difference along the given axis.
>
> The first difference is given by out[i] = a[i+1] - a[i] along the 
> given axis, higher differences are calculated by using diff 
> recursively.
>
> Parameters:
>
> a, array_like, Input array
>
> n, int, optional The number of times values are differenced. 
>
> axis, int, optional The axis along which the difference is taken, default is the last axis.
> ```

Comment: That's it! Now it takes about 0.065 seconds which makes total sense! I'm really surprised that such a simple thing causing so much overhead. Thanks a lot!